# Update single value in reducer object without deleting prior data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

My goal is to update the `pause` value in my ruducer's object without deleting any of the other data.

Here is my ruducer code:

```js
export const initialState = {
  audio: {
    sound: false,
    index: 0,
    name: '',
    image: '',
    username: '',
    pause: false,
  },
};
```

And here is it's case:

```js
case 'TRIGGER_AUDIO':
      return {
        ...state,
        audio: action.payload,
      };
```

Here is how I access the `audio` values:

```js
  const [{ audio }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
```

And this is how I'm trying to update it when I press a button:

```js
<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                dispatch({
                  type: 'TRIGGER_AUDIO',
                  payload: {
                    ...state.audio,
                    pause: true,
                  },
                })
              }>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @lissettdm Please read the first line. I want update "pause" without deleting all of the other data in the object

Comment: What is exactly deleted here? What is other data? In which object is it "deleted"?

Comment: @Virtuoz When I send a new dispatch to update the pause value in my audio object in my intialstate variable, all of the data such as audio.sound, audio.index, etc is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need something like this

```
case 'TRIGGER_AUDIO':
      const audio = {...state.audio, ...action.payload};
      return {
        ...state,
        audio
      };
```

Comment: This works! Can you explain what you did?

Comment: Suppose you have two objects const a = { a: 1, b: 2}; const b = { b: 3, c: 2}. You can use syntax {...a, ...b} to merge these objects and obtain {a: 1, b: 3, c: 2} in result. I just merged state.audio object with your payload and then assign the result to the audio in your state. This is not a replacement, this is merge, so keys won't be "deleted"

Comment: Ah, makes a lot of sense. Thank you!